# regex to capture html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

How would I write this to store the text "allofthistextcaptured" with regex? i dont want "_poster" to be captured. The below javascript is exactly what I need, I just need some regex at the end to capture all the text in the src tag EXCEPT "_poster".

html

```
<div class="postImage"><img src="allofthistextcaptured_poster.jpg" title="" width="640" height="385" /></div>
```

js i have so far

```
var text = $(this).siblings('.postImage').find('img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will a simple `replace()` work for you?

```
var text = $(this).siblings('.postImage').find('img').attr('src').replace('_poster', '');
```

If you want to use RegExp then you can do something like this:

```
var text = $(this).siblings('.postImage').find('img').attr('src').replace(/_poster./, '.');
```

Which looks for `_poster.` and replaces it with `.` but this is pretty-much the same thing as the first example.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/exAXw/

Comment: Agreed, simple replace is much cleaner than regex here.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the searchable string is reduced to only the filename, you can use this regex to capture the name and the extension:

```
([\w]+)(?>_poster)\.([\w]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a generic replace using regEx to strip b/w k and `.` that is anything after `_` and before `.`

```
.replace (/(_[^.*]*)/, '');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BQmE4/)